# OpenERP bug fixing / testing process

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

What is the authentic way to fix bug / test openerp modules.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand after read your question, you want to fix bug and contribute to openerp.

for this you have to post a bug, what a bug you have found go to the launchpad branch of opener (server, addons, openerp-web), and report a bug, with your bug you can proposed your merger purposal also, what a solution you done for this bug.

to post a bug and fix you have to first register with launchpad repository.

first go for register account in launchapd

[image]

after login to launchapd, you have to go to addons or server branch to post a bug
[image]

to report a bug you have to give summary of bug, then detail description of bug steps by steps, if you have soltion then you can attach the patch or pur a merge proposal also.